# Requiring Date and Time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

I need a datetime. I currently have:

Model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:f}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
assetBookingModel.DateFrom = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateFrom)
```

This displays a text box with a date and no time. I can add a calendar extender with a time property without too much problems, but MVC doesn't seem to have any proper validation for this, or add in the time by default.

I have searched the web and there isn't too much help to be found.

What is the best way to go about implementing a Date and Time field, that will not accept only the Date.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'd use, `[CustomValidation]`.  Allows you to create your own validation function.  A few useful examples are here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx